# Image saved twice using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

With the following code, every image is saved two times. How can I skip the image that is already saved?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata


i = 1
soup = make_soup("https://www./")
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    temp = img.get('src')
    image = temp
    if str(image):
        filename = str(i)
        i = i + 1
        imagefile = open(filename + '.png', 'wb')
        imagefile.write(urllib.request.urlopen(image).read())
        imagefile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *set* structure to filter out the duplicates like so:

```
unique_srcs = list(set([img.get('src') for img in soup.findAll('img')]))
for img_src in unique_srcs:
    filename = str(i)
    i = i + 1
    imagefile = open(filename + '.png', 'wb')
    imagefile.write(urllib.request.urlopen(img_src).read())
    imagefile.close()
```

Now, bear in mind that this might change the order of the files. If you can't afford to change the order, you can achieve the same by looping through the `soup.findAll()` list and checking whether each element's *src* is not in an another *unique_list*, then appending that element to that *unique_list* of srcs and then looping over it like I did.

EDIT:
To keep the order, use this code instead of the list comprehension for `unique_srcs` array.

```
unique_srcs = []
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
   if img.get('src') not in unique_srcs:
       unique_srcs.append(img.get('src'))
```

Your first element would then be `unique_srcs[0]` (logo in your case).

Comment: File "C:/Users/hp dv4/PycharmProjects/project/Crawlme.py", line 18, in <module>
    imagefile.write(urllib.request.urlopen(img_src).read())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Comment: @user9053914 Woops, pardon me, I left out the `'img'` parameter in `findAll()`, edited

Comment: @user9053914 Edited

Comment: How can I get the same order for the saved images? I tried it but I am able to save only the first image.